# iOS11 UICollectionSectionHeader clipping scroll indicator

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios11

I created a single view project and added a collectionView. I registered a simple subclass of UICollectionReusableView

```
final class TestReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  }
  ...
}
```

Set datasource and delegate to self

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: kHeader, for: indexPath)
    return headerView
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return cell
  }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 88)
  }
}
```

The result is the section header seems to be positioned above the vertical scroll indicator. However, if I run the app against a 10.3.1 simulator, the behavior works as I'd expect.

[image: Red section header is on top of the scroll indicator]

Comment: I have also encountered similar issue with iOS 11.0 where section header is positioned above all views. Everything works fine in 10.3.

Comment: Definitely looks like iOS 11.0+ issue. I'm running into it also. Closest RADAR I can find is this: http://www.openradar.me/34308893

Answer (score 6):

this works for me:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplaySupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (SystemVersionGraterOrEqual(11)) {
        if ([elementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
            view.layer.zPosition = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Good catch, although the whole problem seems like a bug, because playing with the z position should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't try it out but can you try adding this to your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let flow = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
flow.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Comment: This just pins the section header to the top of the collectionView. The problem in question is that section headers are clipping the vertical scroll indicator

Answer (score 1):

Well even I encountered the same issue in my app and it was slated for release in 2 weeks. I couldn't have time to do research on why this is failing only in iOS 11. Hence the quick work around which I did is by replacing the usage of headerView with footerView since footerView doesn't have this problem.